# Convert LCh to standard Munsell color system

Tags: r, colors, color-space, lab-color-space

I would like to convert colors defined in LCh terms to Munsell color system. For example, I have LCh values for Blue color as below:

```
L = 46
C = 48
h = 240
```

But I require to check whether the above falls within a standard which indicate Blue as below:

```
Centroid 2.5PB 4/10
Hue limits - from 7.5B to 5PB
Value limits - from 3 to 5.2
Chroma limits - from 8 to >8
```

Purpose is to check the agreement with this standard.

I have almost no knowledge on color systems as such and trying to acquire something, but its somewhat complex and any help here is appreciated. You may redirect to any online converter or formulae page as well as any solution in [R] as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with Python I would recommend you to use the amazing colour-science librairy: https://www.colour-science.org/

You could then ask your question on [the discourse](https://colour-science.discourse.group/) if you don't manage to find the way to get a result with it.